# How can I get the last dialled number and call duration via adb?

Tags: adb, call-history

I'm creating a computer system for telemarketing.
I'm using adb commands to dial numbers [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4927028/1016772)
Is it possible to get last dialled number and call duration via adb?
If it is, how?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out ? in my case, the android isn't rooted, so accessing `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts` isn't possible ( `permission denied` )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to pull

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db
```

as it contains all the call logs, and then filter through?

Something like:

```
cp data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db /sdcard/MyTelephoneDatabase.db
```

Comment: ...will try it tomorrow and confirm if it works or not
PS this is sqlite database?

Comment: Yes - This is a sqlite database :)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I answered it long time ago.
You do it like that

```
c:\adb\adb.exe shell sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db "SELECT * FROM calls order by _id desc limit 1;"
```

But it may be different in different android versions. As far as I remember worked on KitKat

Comment: Just note, that `sqlite3` *creates* a database with the same name incase `contacts2.db` is not found, so I would advise first to run a command to make sure it exists